# How to find analytical solution for $E(t)$ for the heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

For the given PDE system how do I find the total energy without having to calculate the complete solution?

[image]

I've tried equating $E(0)$ and $E(\infty)$ using the steady-state solution, but to no avail.

Comment: please use latex

Comment: The image you have posted doesn't actually have a question attached to it and I'm not entirely sure what you're question is. I guess, if you're asking to find an explicit form for $E$, you could compute $E'(t)$ yielding an ODE $$E' + 3E = \int_{0}^{1} e^{-t}u_{xx}$$ which can then be solved with initial condition $$E(0) = \int_{0}^{1} u(x,0) dx$$ I get $$E(t) = \frac{e^{-t}}{2} + \frac{e^{-3t}}{6}$$